# Syntax Error while building ns3.29 on ubuntu 18.04.4

Tags: simulation, ns-3

I've installed all per-requisites [from](https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation). Build fails with the following error by using `./waf` command.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 125, in compile
    _optimize=optimize)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 741, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/visualizer/visualizer/svgitem.py", line 123
    raise AttributeError, 'unknown property %s' % pspec.name
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/py_compile.py", line 129, in compile
    raise py_exc
py_compile.PyCompileError:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3/dist-packages/visualizer/visualizer/svgitem.py", line 123
    raise AttributeError, 'unknown property %s' % pspec.name
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Do you prefer to use python with ns3?

Comment: @a4arshad I guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable python. First you need to clean your previous failed build and then configure by disabling the python.

```
./waf distclean
./waf --disable-python configure
./waf
```

Comment: Thank you, 'build' finished successfully.